# robotframework: How can I run test cases until one of them fails?

Tags: robotframework, stress-testing

Here is my situation: I need to run number of test cases repeatedly over long period of time (Stress test + Longevity test). In the test case, there are number of events that should be passed all the time. However, I would like to catch any expected failure.

Is there a way to set robot test suite to keep executing over period of time or until it encounter a failure?

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly can do an endurance test in Robot Framework, you may find that too much memory is consumed and may cause the interpreter to exit prematurely with a MemoryError. If you implement your test as a keyword, you can run your "test" many times with a for loop. In the below example, Scenario is where your test code would go. This is just a simulation that will fail after 200 runs.

```
*** Variables ***
${ITERATION}      ${1}

*** Test Cases ***
Endurance Test
    [Timeout]    4 hours
    :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1000
    \    Scenario

*** Keywords ***
Scenario
    Set Suite Variable    ${ITERATION}    ${ITERATION+1}
    Run Keyword If    ${ITERATION} > 200    Fail    You wore me out
```

Comment: To overcome a MemoryError, you could write a script that runs one test with Robot Framework repeatedly and checks the return code. A non-zero return code indicates a problem like a test failing. see http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#return-codes

Comment: as written the test will fail after 4 hours even though the SUT is fine. You could add code to check the elapsed time and exit gracefully if needed.

Comment: The problem is that I have many robot scripts need to be run in this big loop. And yes, I think I see the MemoryError problem once awhile if I ran all the tests. Thanks anyway. I think I will end up to write a wrapper to do this execute tests in chunks and parse the result.